# Cropping does not work in Neos back-end, beta5

Tags: neoscms

Cropping in Neos back-end throws this exception (for Neos beta5):

`Uncaught exception #1297759968 in line 271 of /usr/local/www/apache24/data/_sprint2/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Mvc_Controller_Argument.php: Exception while property mapping for target type "TYPO3\TYPO3CR\Domain\Model\Node", at property path "": Exception while property mapping for target type "TYPO3\Media\Domain\Model\ImageInterface", at property path "": Could not open stream for resource af0c55f536c860b1d44ce0769f4a1ab52d15b6bd ("company_foldout_short.png") from collection "persistent" while trying to create a temporary local copy. - See also: 20150708145304930495.txt
    previousException => Uncaught exception #1297759968 in line 260 of /usr/local/www/apache24/data/_sprint2/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_TYPO3CR_TypeConverter_NodeConverter.php: Exception while property mapping for target type "TYPO3\Media\Domain\Model\ImageInterface", at property path "": Could not open stream for resource af0c55f536c860b1d44ce0769f4a1ab52d15b6bd ("company_foldout_short.png") from collection "persistent" while trying to create a temporary local copy.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For me it look like a missing original resource, can you try to search if the resource exist first:

> ls Data/Persistent/Resources/a/f/0/c/af0c55f536c860b1d44ce0769f4a1ab52d15b6bd

Answer (score 0):

Please try `./flow doctrine:migrate` and after that flush the cache.
This should help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this did not work. Can you reproduce the error?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt the last migration (Version20150611154419) of the Package "TYPO3.Flow" replaces the location of the assets.
I had the same issue like you and it resolved it for me.
Another possibility is to change the version from beta5 to the branch 2.0.
Maybe this could help you.